# How do I alter the values of individual Attributes of a Dynamic view?

Tags: android, layout

If I'm creating RelativeLayout of my own in code (not in XML) and wish to set its various attributes (android:layout_centerVertical, etc) what is the syntax for doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to use `LayoutParams`. This should help you out:

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.ALIGN_PARENT_LEFT, RelativeLayout.TRUE);
Button button1;
button1.setLayoutParams(params);

params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
params.addRule(RelativeLayout.RIGHT_OF, button1.getId());
Button button2;
button2.setLayoutParams(params);
```

You need to create the `LayoutParams` object and then use `addRule()` to add rules to it. Then you just set the parameters to the `View` you want. Be careful when importing `LayoutParams` because there are different imports for different types of `View`. I think you'll want the one called `RelativeLayout.LayoutParams`

[Here is a link to the dev guide for extra help](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html)

Comment: Ah! yes... importing the right LayoutParams (the one that's part of RelativeLayout) is the key to everything. Thanks very much.